How do I fix copy-paste not working in Arch?
I have Arch Linux Hyprland. Can’t copy paste things from Google Chrome to VSC. Any ideas? I feel like I’ve tried everything…
I tried xclip, xsel, updating the system, rebooting. It only doesn’t work when I copy paste from Chrome specifically. I need to use it because of dev tools.

I use copyq:

sudo pacman -S copyq xclip

run copyq& (i think there's even a way to have it run at login)

if you want a UI to choose from multiple copied items and manipulate the clipboard you could run:
copyq | copyq toggle &


Now you have a clipboard and you can use the middle mouse in the terminal to paste the contents.
Note that arch comes with vim-minimal so inside vim you won't be able to use the clipboard. Just install gvim instead (it will ask to remove the vim-minimal, which is ok) and this installs a terminal vim as well, this time having the clipboard capabilities (press "*p or middle mouse in insert mode to paste).
Unfortunately I don't know how to paste various copyq items into vim, it only works in terminal. I suppose the vim clipboard register works somewhat differently.

There's even a way to make it floating window in Hyprland:
windowrulev2 = float,class:(copyq)
windowrulev2 = move onscreen cursor,class:(copyq)

